# C++ Implementation of scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_rotvec

Tags: c++, opencv, scipy

I am currently converting object detection project from python to C++. I came across few code line which uses scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_rotvec. Is there any C++ implementation of corresponding functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you use OpenCV as specified in your question tags, you can use the [`Rodrigues()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga61585db663d9da06b68e70cfbf6a1eac) function that transform a 3D rotation vector to a 3x3 rotation matrix and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) 's [AngleAxis](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1AngleAxis.html).